# emit event(address(this))

Tags: solidity

I'm starting to read the Ethereum ressources and started with this [article](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/ethereum-in-depth-part-1-968981e6f833/).
I'm struggling to understand what the fallback will do in the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.4;

contract MyContract {
  event Log(address addr);

  fallback() external payable{
    emit Log(address(this));
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

I understand what an event is. From the documentation:"this(current contract’s type):the current contract, explicitly convertible to Address". 
My understanding is that the fallback will always log the same address (the address of MyContract). Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes...............

Comment: Thank you for your reply (it doesn't change the anser but I wrongly updated the contract; it shouldn't be a falllback function but a constructor.)

Comment: Same answer. The expression `address(this)` will always evaluate to the same value in every function of a given instance of the contract (i.e., if you call the same function but from different instances of the contract, you will get different results).

Answer (score 1):

The expression `address(this)` will evaluate to the same value in every function which uses it, when called on a given instance of the contract.

Of course, when such function is called on different instances of the contract, this expression will evaluate to a different value for each instance.